# How to come back from screen to main menu in libgdx

Tags: menu, libgdx, screen

I am newbie in libgdx and go very slowly.
Actually I try to develop a game using libgdx. At this time I have a problem with screens and mainmenu.

I start the app from mainclass

```
public class mainclass extends Game implements ApplicationListener {
private MainMenu mainMenuScreen;


@Override
public void create() {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    mainMenuScreen = new MainMenu(this);

    this.setScreen(mainMenuScreen);

}

}
```

From this I open the mainmenu and this step work. From mainmenu I open the game screen and this step work. From the keydown event of the gamescreen class

```
public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
    if (keycode == Input.Keys.BACK) {

        this.hide();
        game.setScreen(mainMenuScreen);
        System.out.println("back........");
        //Gdx.app.exit();

    }
    return false;
}
```

I wish come back to the main menu. The event is recognized(I see back........ on the logcat) but the mainmenu isn't showed. Please someone could tell me why this don't work and a possible solution?

Comment: What happens instead of `mainMenuScreen` showing? Do you get a black screen? Or is some kind of exception is thrown?

Comment: nullexceptionpointer on this line           game.setScreen(mainMenuScreen);  but game is declared as   private mainclass game;  mainmenuscreen is declared  private MainMenu mainMenuScreen; and I have also mainMenuScreen=new MainMenu(game); in the constructor of mainmenu...

Comment: Can you add the exception stack to the question? That way it is easier to understand what's going on.

Comment: 12-07 09:42:52.931 25128-25149/? E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.rino.mytestgame.android, PID: 25128
12-07 09:42:52.931 25128-25149/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.rino.mytestgame.mainclass.setScreen(com.badlogic.gdx.Screen)' on a null object reference
12-07 09:42:52.931 25128-25149/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.rino.mytestgame.GameScreen.keyDown(GameScreen.java:185)              these are the logcat lines....

Comment: add this comment because I solved the problem(and this could be usefoul for someone...) game was null... the error was when I calling the new screen with a game =null .....